# Search for String in the queue

Tags: java, queue

I'm somewhat new to programming, so sorry if this is stupid..

I have a Queue of strings and I want code for search About element "E" in this code .
because everytime this error shows :

> string cannot be converted to char.

```
public class Queue<Character> {
private java.util.LinkedList<Character> list = new java.util.LinkedList<Character>();
public Queue() {
}
public void clear() {
list.clear();
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
return list.isEmpty();
}
public Character firstEl() {
return list.getFirst();
}
public Character dequeue() {
return list.removeFirst();
}
public void enqueue(Character el) {
list.addLast(el);
}
public String toString() {
return list.toString();
}

public static void main(String []arg) {
Queue<String> student = new Queue<String>();
student.enqueue("A");
student.enqueue("B");
student.enqueue("C");
student.enqueue("D");
student.enqueue("E");
student.enqueue("F");
System.out.println(student.toString());
String mStr = student.dequeue();
System.out.println(mStr + " came first and being served first");
}
}
```

Comment: This runs fine on ideone ([demo](http://ideone.com/g4Td0s)). On what line do you have a problem?

Comment: What compiler are you using and what version of Java are you on? This runs fine for me in eclipse with Java 7

Answer (score 1):

```
student.enqueue("A");
```

Should be replaced with:

```
student.enqueue('A');
```

Double quotes create a string and enqueue expects a character.

Comment: The code posted by the op works correctly.  What you provided will result in a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

"I have a Queue of strings and I want code for search About element "E" in this code"

I think you were asking for code to find some element in your linked list?

```
public int find(java.lang.String string){
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i).equals(string)) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This code takes some string as an argument, and if the element exists in the list, returns the index at which it was found. If it does not exist, it returns -1.

If you do `System.out.println(student.find("E"));` right after you print the linkedlist, you will get 4.